# use ros header files in c++ project

Tags: c++, rosbag, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS. I want to include ros header files (for example #include <rosbag/bag.h>) in a c++ project. I do not want to create a node and start roscore. How can I include this header + other dependencies in a CMakeLists file ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282955/use-ros-header-files-in-c++-project/) by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See #q238955

catkin (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials) which makes use of CMake is the best supported way to go, otherwise you could do cmake on your own like:

```
find_package(roscpp REQUIRED)
include_directories(${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
```

Replace roscpp with whatever library you need.

pkg-config also can get ros libraries and includes.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on 2018-02-16**:
@lucasw Thanks a lot. This is just what I was looking for.

**Comment by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on 2018-02-19**:
using these lines in my CMakeList :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(writeBag)
find_package(roscpp REQUIRED)
I get this error :CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package): By not providing "Findroscpp.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package

**Comment by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on 2018-02-19**:
../..
configuration file provided by "roscpp", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
of the following names:

```
roscppConfig.cmake
roscpp-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set..

**Comment by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on 2018-02-19**:
I fixed this issue : I needed to source the ROS setup.bash file...